# Where do house elves come from?

Tags: harry-potter, house-elves

Just like my other question this has got nothing on it anywhere, where do the house elves originally come from?

Comment: If you’re asking how they were enslaved, that seems to be similar to your previous question (I assume some wizards used magic to do it).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How did the house elves start serving wizards?](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/60922/how-did-the-house-elves-start-serving-wizards)

Comment: If you’re wondering about their species history, on the other hand…I suspect they evolved, like humans. Magical folk (witches/wizards) and house-elves, as well as Muggles (real-world humans) are probably all apes of some description. But they could have been created by some deity (as might the humans of *Harry Potter*, for that matter), or even have been magically engineered by wizards.

Comment: Well.. Sometimes a mommy elf and a daddy elf.. you see...

Comment: @Adamant - In Harry Potter, wizards originate from Mars and Muggles from mushrooms. (At least according to Hambledon Quince, that is.)

Comment: I meant what country they originally came from.

Comment: Well, there are counterparts or related beings  in other countries. They do not just live in Britain, though their enslavement may be particular to there.

Comment: @Awesome Add that into your question.

Answer (score 2):

## We don't know.

Rowling has not given us the backstory of how house-elves originated.